# Suppose A and B are sets. What can you prove about P(A\B)\(P(A)\ P(B))?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

This post is regarding Question 3.7.3 of Velleman's How to Prove It. It is:

Suppose A and B are sets. What can you prove about P(A\B) 
(P(A)\ P(B))? (No, it’s not equal to ∅. Try some ex am ples
and see what you get.)

The following is a proof that it is equal to { {} }.

[What can be said about $P (A \setminus B) \setminus (P (A) \setminus P (B))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092603/what-can-be-said-about-p-a-setminus-b-setminus-p-a-setminus-p-b)

But, as the question suggested, I tried an example (see below) and it clearly isn't the same. Can someone point out where I went wrong.

Suppose A = {1,2} and B={2,3}.

A\B= {1,3} and P(A/B)= { {}, {1}, {3}, {1,3} }

Then P(A)={ {}, {1}, {2}, {1,2} } and P(B)={ {}, {2}, {3}, {2,3} }.

We have P(A)\P(B)= { {1}, {1,2} }

So, P(A\B)(P(A)\ P(B))= { {}, {3}, {1,3} }

Comment: $A\setminus B=\{1\}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can be said about $P (A \setminus B) \setminus (P (A) \setminus P (B))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092603/what-can-be-said-about-p-a-setminus-b-setminus-p-a-setminus-p-b)

Comment: Now that the mistake of algebra has been pointed out, I believe there is no reason not to close this as a duplicate of the post it was objecting to.